# radio input validation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to validate my radio input by female and male value, how can I it? 
This in my code:

```
<span>Gender:</span>
<input type="radio"  name="gender" id="male" />Male
<input type="radio"  name="gender" id="female" />Female
<div id="e4" class="error2">Please choose your gender</div>
```

Comment: Please use a label element associated with each of your radio inputs via for/id attributes ("[Associate Labels with Elements](http://www.jimthatcher.com/webcourse8.htm)") (then an unstyled fieldset and a legend for _Gender_ will be even better but first the labels ^^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:checked` selector and the `length` property to make sure an item was selected:

```
if (!$('input[name="gender"]:checked').length) {
    $('#e4').show(); // display the error div
}
```

Comment: will `.length` not throw if nothing is selected? `length of undefined...`

Comment: No, the `$()` construct will always return an object, therefore it will always have a `length` property.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(':radio').change(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('#e4').hide()
  } else {
    $('#e4').show()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Gender:</span>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="Male" />Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="Female" />Female
<div id="e4" class="error2">Please choose your gender</div>
```

Try this way

Answer (score 2):

Following is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/us7e1yx3/1/)

#### Code

```js
function validate(){
 var value = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
    if(!value){
     $("#e4").fadeIn()
    }
}

$("input[name='gender']").on("change", function(){
 $("#e4").fadeOut()
})
```

```css
.error2{
    color:red;
}

.hide{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Gender:</span>
<input type="radio"  name="gender" id="male" />Male
<input type="radio"  name="gender" id="female" />Female
<div id="e4" class="error2 hide">Please choose your gender</div><br/>
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```